# Working with Android widgets

Tags: java, android, xml, widget, android-widget

I am experimenting with android widgets and tried to make a simple 4x2 widget that displays a different proverb each day, for this I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidauthority.com/create-simple-android-widget-608975/) and everything seems to work fine no errors or crashes whatsoever but the problem is I can't seem to find the widgets in the widget sections on my phone to drag and drop it here's my code so far:

**JAVA**

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
Random rand = new Random();
String [] daily_proverbs = new String[]{
    /** list of proverbs goes here */
};

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        String prvb = getRandomProverb();

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.sayings, prvb);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
public String getRandomProverb(){
    return this.daily_proverbs[rand.nextInt(164)];
}
}
```

**XML - the widget provider:** here I get this warning: `The following classes could not be found: -include` and I tried fixing it by adding the missing `include` and nothing happened

```
<appwidget-provider
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="140dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_widget"
android:resizeMode="none"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">
</appwidget-provider>
```

**WIDGET LAYOUT XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="@color/white">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="title goes here"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/electricBlue"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sayings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="proverbs goes here"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/actionButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text here"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/electricBlue"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through all of that I was able to create a widget without any trouble by simply:

> 1- Right click on layout
>
> 2- Go to "new" --> Widget --> App Widget

That's it and everything will be set up

Answer (score 1):

Have you added widget in AndroidManifest file?

```
<receiver android:name="Widget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/your_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: layout_width and layout_height are not valid attributes instead add attributes as minHeight and minWidth in widget provider xml

Comment: Is it working now? If not can you post your widget layout file?

Comment: it's not working, and there it goes I updated my question and added the widget layout

Comment: I tried executing your code. It works for me. Changed following:           Added </RelativeLayout> tag in WIDGET LAYOUt XML.                             <appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">
</appwidget-provider><br/>

Comment: Even its crashing as we havent added values to daily_proverbs array.So added some values to it and changed return this.daily_proverbs[rand.nextInt(1)];

Comment: do you have a "The following classes could not be found" warning in the widget_info.xml ?

Comment: No I dont have this warning and I am able to add widget <appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_widget"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard">
</appwidget-provider> .                                                                                     Path to store widget info is:  /res/xml/widget_info.xml. Please check you have place file at valid location.

Comment: in the `res/xml/widget_info.xml` is the preview showing correctly ? because for me in `activity_widget.xml` the preview is fine but in `widget_info.xml` I don't get the preview

Comment: I also dont see preview for res/xml/widget_info.xml. Its fine , we get preview for layout files only. Please refer http://www.androidauthority.com/create-simple-android-widget-608975/ . Its a good tutorial to create a simple widget.

Comment: I can't even find the widget in the widgets section, and yes that was the tutorial I was following since the beginning